# ASP app cannot open RSA key container (NTE_BAD_KEYSET error)

Tags: asp.net, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Having difficulty making CryptAcquireContext work for a .NET app. I've created the key, but it's throwing error NTE_BAD_KEYSET.

The documentation suggests that the trouble is with permissions, but I'm not quite sure who to give permission to. So far have tried:

SYSTEM
NETWORK
NETWORK SERVICE
ASPNET
Administrators
Cryptographic Operators

No dice.

Any ideas?

This is a machine key.

UPDATE: Gave access to EVERYONE and that seems to have worked. However, it seems like a bad security practice. The question stands: who should actually be getting access?

Comment: Ain't that the truth.

Comment: You'll most likely want to assign access to the account that the app pool runs under. Or impersonate in your code some other user with access. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede.ASPX